# Django Rest Api adding members (users) to a Class model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I wanted to implement a student class system where anyone can create a class and others can join.
So far I have it so each class has a creator and members in it.  I'm trying to get it so that when the user creates the class they are automatically added as a member as well, but I'm not sure how to add members to a class.  Im able to do it through the python shell but not in the Class view through the api.

Eventually I want you to be able to go to /auth/classes//join and have that user join that class as well as /auth/classes//leave.  Any help is greatly appreciated :)

model.py

```
class Class(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    class_discription = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 
    creator = models.ForeignKey('users.User', related_name='creator', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    members = models.ManyToManyField('users.User')  

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created']


    def addMember(self, *vars, **kwargs):
        self.membebrs.add(User)
        return super().save(*vars, **kwargs)

    def deleteMember(self, *vars, **kwargs):
        self.membebrs.remove(User)
        return super().save(*vars, **kwargs)
```

view.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from rest_framework import viewsets
from classes.serializers import ClassSerializer
from rest_framework import permissions
from rest_framework.response import Response
from classes.models import Class
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework import status, viewsets
from users.models import User

# Create your views here.
class ClassViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows classes to be viewed or edited.
    """
    
    queryset = Class.objects.all().order_by('-name')
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
    serializer_class = ClassSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        user = self.request.user
        serializer.save(creator=user)
```

serializer.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from classes.models import Class
from users.serializers import UserSerializer


class ClassSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    creator = UserSerializer(many=False, required=False)
    members = UserSerializer(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Class
        fields = ['name', 'id', 'creator', 'members']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does adding the creator to the `members` set on `save` work? Something like this...

```
class Class(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    class_discription = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    .
    .

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.members.add(self.creator)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there:

```py
class ClassViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows classes to be viewed or edited.
    """
    
    queryset = Class.objects.all().order_by('-name')
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
    serializer_class = ClassSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        obj = serializer.save()
        obj.creator = self.request.user
        obj.save()
```

Please note that you need to submit *nothing* of the creator object. So you can't submit a payload like:

```
{
    "creator": {
         "username": "",
    },
    "members": [],
    "name" : "This Does NOT work"
}
```

Because then creator will be validated and fail. Creator needs to be absent in the payload, when creating a new class:

```
{
    "members": [],
    "name": "This should work"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for responding, I changed views.py to look like this:

```
# Create your views here.
class ClassViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows classes to be viewed or edited.
    """
    
    queryset = Class.objects.all().order_by('-name')
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
    serializer_class = ClassSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        obj = serializer.save()
        obj.members.add(self.request.user)
        obj.save()
```

however it still throws an error, am I understanding you wrong?

```
IntegrityError at /api/classes/
NOT NULL constraint failed: classes_class.creator_id

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/classes/
Django Version: 3.0.7
```

I also couldn't get the code which updates members every time the class is saved to work.